# Can't install Homebrew on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, install, permission, homebrew, package-management

I followed the simple instructions on Homebrew's homepage:

```
Paste this at a terminal prompt:
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731)"
```

But I get the following permission errors.  What is the proper way to install Homebrew on Mac OS X Lion?

```
$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731)"
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/Library/Formula/...
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/...

Press enter to continue
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod o+w /usr/local
mkdir: /usr/local/Cellar: Permission denied
mkdir: /usr/local/etc: Permission denied
mkdir: /usr/local/include: Permission denied
mkdir: /usr/local/lib: Permission denied
mkdir: /usr/local/Library: Permission denied
mkdir: /usr/local/sbin: Permission denied
mkdir: /usr/local/share: Permission denied
mkdir: /usr/local/var: Permission denied
mkdir: /usr/local/.git: Permission denied
Failed during: /bin/mkdir /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/etc /usr/local/include /usr/local/lib /usr/local/Library /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/share /usr/local/var /usr/local/.git
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `sudo /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731)"`.

Comment: I think that would've worked, I was reluctant to because I didn't want to mess with Homebrew's mechanism for enabling non-sudo required installs.  The problem seemed to be that Homebrew added o+w permission to `/usr/local`, but OS X Lion's main user is part of the group of `/usr/local`, so adding g+w worked.  I assume I can now safely remove with `sudo chmod g-w /usr/local`?

Comment: I have to admit I just posted a knee-jerk "Permission issue, try sudo" answer. I don't actually __know__ the answer, but I presume you could indeed try that :)

Answer (score 1):

I just struggled with the same problem, but instead of manually entering any commands<sup>†</sup>, I used **[gist: 768518](https://gist.github.com/768518)** to do the dirty stuff for me. Worked like a charm—and you won't need any `sudo`ing!

The aforementioned gist (aptly described as "Fix permissions on /usr/local for Homebrew") only *fixes* the permissions, i.e. it doesn't install Homebrew despite the fact it is a fork of the [installation script](https://gist.github.com/323731).

---

<sup>†) other than the required `$ chmod a+x fix_homebrew.rb` and `$ ./fix_homebrew.rb` of course</sup>

Answer (score 1):

the official oneliner from brew.sh is this...

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"

why would you like to use a outdated gist version and not the original script???

Answer (score 0):

Github has [a beautiful app for Mac](http://mac.github.com/) that eliminates the painful commandline process (if the commandline is not your thing that is ;-))

Comment: It would be rather contradictory, though, if one wishes to install Homebrew while command-line not being his "thing" :-D

Comment: How would GitHub for Mac help with installing Homebrew?

Answer (score 0):

try these, these works for me..

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go/install)"
```

Comment: mxcl/homebrew repo is now homebrew/homebrew